# Raspberry Pi 4 with latest raspbian buster serial gpio not working

Tags: gpio, serial, raspberry-pi-os

I'm trying to use the GPIO TX and RX on RPi 4 with the latest raspbian. What I did to test is:

- Installed latest raspbian buster.
- Run update, upgrade and firmware upgrade.
- Edited raspi-config to enable serial ("no" on console and "yes" on hardware serial port")
- Add at /boot/config.txt the text: "dtoverlay=disable-bt"
- Checked /boot/cmdline.txt and there are no signs of port /dev/ttyAMA0 being used there.
- Connected the TX and RX of Raspberry Pi GPIO together (for testing purposes before I connect it to external devices.)
- Reboot
- Create a python3 script with pyserial module just to simple send and receive what I type.
- The port name is /dev/ttyAMA0.
- It does not work, nothing is I send is received back.
- I searched all over the internet and nothing seems to work for RPi4 with the raspbian buster. Can anyone guide me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why aren't you using `/dev/serial0` ?

Comment: Why on earth do new users have this fixation with disabling BT? Just leave it alone and use /dev/serial0

Comment: Should I change anything besides the port name? Still does not work.

Comment: We need connection photos and software listings.

Comment: @Milliways: There's confusing documentation that says BT can't be used with the primary serial port. I initially fell into this trap as well. If you read the description on "disable-bt" in `/boot/overlays/README` you can really get the idea that you have to do that in order for Uart0 to work.

Comment: @Milliways: The readme states that: "Disable onboard Bluetooth on Pi 3B, 3B+, 3A+, 4B and Zero W, restoring UART0/ttyAMA0 over GPIOs 14 & 15." How would a beginner know that UART0 is not the one that is generally used on GPIOs 14&15? And that Foundation Documentation leaves more questions open than it answers, because it's to general. What I would need as a beginner was something like "on the Pi4, to use the Uart on GPIO 14&15, these are the settings you need:..." and not something technical about MiniUart, PL011, primary, secondary, etc.

Comment: @Milliways All I'm saying is that the documentation that many would consider "official" also has room for improvement. Of course, there's always even worse information to be found on the net. We both know that SO is a good place to look for answers on such questions, but some may just click the first unsourced youtube clip.

Comment: If you want help you need to post your code and the output of `ls -l /dev/serial*`